# When formatting multiline statements in IntelliJ IDEA, can I align operators?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, code-formatting

I'm looking at the options in IntelliJ IDEA 12 and I can't let this go. So please help me stop wasting time on it.

This is some code from my Build.scala:

```
val logging =
  Seq(
    "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.0.13",
    "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.5",
    "com.weiglewilczek.slf4s" % "slf4s_2.9.1" % "1.0.7"
  )
```

I'd like it to look like this:

```
val logging =
  Seq(
    "ch.qos.logback"          % "logback-classic" % "1.0.13",
    "org.slf4j"               % "slf4j-api"       % "1.7.5",
    "com.weiglewilczek.slf4s" % "slf4s_2.9.1"     % "1.0.7"
  )
```

And I prefer create that automatically with the code formatter. In my (unreliable) memory I had this working in IntelliJ IDEA before, but I can't find which options to turn on.

Do you know where this option is hiding?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15001403/code-formatting-how-to-align-multiline-code-to-special-characters – don't forget to vote on the [feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-5380)

Comment: I think it's related, but not necessarily a duplicate (if I understand the scala compilation process correctly). @0__ this means the option isn't there right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many *Align multiline* options in IDEA, but none has an effect on this syntax.

[This feature is not in IDEA 12](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-5380). The only option that I could think of was to manually format the code that way. You should vote for [this alignment feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-5380) and anxiously await IDEA 13.